# Transforming geographical points to geometry in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type

I have a `PointField(geography=True)` field in Django, which is translated into the following Postgres type: `geography(Point,4326)`.

I set the `geography` field to `True` because I thought it made sense for storing coordinates of physical locations in the world, but inserting points received from Google Maps causes them to be transformed inside the DB.

So for instance, I put the following point into Postgres: `SRID=4326;POINT (30.2484381 -97.7503308)`:

```sql
UPDATE "table" SET "location" = ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT (30.2484381 -97.7503308)') WHERE "uuid" = '1d604100-b838-4cd3-9ca3-f600648ed3d8';
```

Now, when I try to retrieve the point I just stored, it comes out transformed:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsEWKT("location") FROM "table" WHERE "uuid" = '1d604100-b838-4cd3-9ca3-f600648ed3d8'
```

This is the result: `SRID=4326;POINT(30.2484381 -82.2496692)`.

I have lot of points stored that have been transformed into a geographical system, and now I want to transform them back into the geometrical points that were inserted originally.

Is there a PostGIS function to do this?

Comment: 1) https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html : "Points are always expressed in long lat form"

Comment: 2) did the update affect any rows?

Comment: Yes, the update affected one row, which did not have a "location" set previously. You can re-create the effect with an empty table. Also, I didn't understand your first comment.

Comment: paraphrase: "Points are always expressed in (longitude latitude) order"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are passing the coordinates in (lat lon) order instead of (lon lat) order.
[ST_GeogFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html) :" Points are always expressed in long lat form"

The record with ID = 1 your original coordinates and ID = 2 has a valid latitude of -90.  ID =3 is your coordinates reversed to proper order.

```
drop table if exists "test";
create table "test" (id integer, "location" geography(POINT,4326));
insert into  "test" values (1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)')), (2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)')), (3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)'));
update "test" set "location" =  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT (30.2484381 -97.7503308)') where id = 1;
update "test" set "location" =  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT (30.2484381 -90)') where id = 2;
update "test" set "location" =  ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT (-97.7503308 30.2484381)') where id = 3;
select id, ST_AsEWKT("location") from "test";
```

returns:

```
id, st_asewkt
1,  SRID=4326;POINT(30.2484381 -82.2496692)
2,  SRID=4326;POINT(30.2484381 -90)
3,  SRID=4326;POINT(-97.7503308 30.2484381)
```

The -97 latitude is invalid and somehow returns -82.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some interest as part of the Boundless: Intro to PostGIS chapter 18.3 discusses casting to geometry. [Here is a link](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html#casting-to-geometry). By the looks of the tutorial it seems you just append `::geometry` to the end of your value you wish to change.  So I guess in your case you would do:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT("location"::geometry) FROM "table" WHERE "uuid" = '1d604100-b838-4cd3-9ca3-f600648ed3d8'
```

Comment: This gives me the exact same result. It casts the type, but does not actually transform the coordinates.